# Making multiple multi-line plots from one matrix

Tags: r, plot, matplotlib-widget

I'm wondering if there's a way to combine the apply function along with the `matplot` function to generate a new plot for every n columns in a matrix.

I currently have a matrix with 1350 rows with 640 columns. I'm plotting the values for all the rows for every 8 columns using `matplot`:

```
png("cmpd1.png")
matplot(data[,1:8], type="l", y-lab="z-score", axes = F) 
axis(side=2)
dev.off()
```

I want to automate this a bit and have the column values shift by eight each loop and the label on the png to change by one. 
Can someone please give directions?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. You can improve your question by take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about how to ask [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: by the way: it is `ylab` not `y-lab`

Comment: I need them for a publication so using pdf isn't an option :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a version with `lapply()` but a loop does the job as well

```
for(i in seq(1,ncol(data),8)){
  png(paste0("cmpd",i,".png"))
  matplot(data[,i:(i+7)], type="l", ylab="z-score", axes = F) 
  axis(side=2)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: It should be `i:(i+7)`. Like this there are 9 columns at a time.

Comment: This worked, except for the fact that it changed each png by eight too, but I just made another variable for that. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer with `vapply()` and formatted plot names. The closed device id will be returned.

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(100*128),nrow = 100,ncol = 128)
vapply(seq(from=1,to=ncol(data)-8,by=8), 
   FUN = function (x) {
     png(paste0("cmpd",formatC(width = 3, format = "d", flag="0", x=x%/%8),".png"))
     matplot(data[,x:(x+8)], type="l", ylab="z-score", axes = F) 
     invisible(dev.off())
     },
   FUN.VALUE=integer(1)
)
```